# How to specify branch dependencies between API and front end for integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, git, continuous-integration, travis-ci

We've got an Angular app backed by a Rails API.  The Angular code and Rails code live in separate repos.  When we build new features we use feature branches, so we might have e.g.

`angular/foobar`

depending on

`rails/foobar`

How can we tell Travis that `angular/foobar` depends on `rails/foobar` when running integration tests?

More broadly, is there a better way to run integration tests across front end and API repos that what we're considering?  This has to bee a solved problem but I haven't found anything out there that's very helpful.

Comment: Could you make one a submodule of the other? That way you can pick a specific commit.

Answer (score 1):

API/UI development across multiple repos is not a solved problem, and all drops of wisdom is more than welcomed.

As for me, this is what I recommend: always develop on the UI side against the API `master` branch (or any branch you consider your base branch).

The thinking behind this is: changes on the API must be done first before implementing new UI features depending on these changes. Make sure the changes on the API don't break the actual UI version (your UI `master` or base branch).

At this point, your actual UI client still works with the new API changes. Now's the time to start working on the UI.

This workflow will also help in the deployment process, as you know that you'll be able to deploy the API first, then ask users to upgrade the app.

I tried to keep my answer simple for the sake of being brief, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Your approach works fine, but doesn't take into account the possibility of working *in parallel* on backend and frontend (which usually is something you want to do). If that's the case, the frontend part can only be tested with the backend branch

Comment: My answer was addressing the integration tests issue. As for parallel development, the workflow you might adopt depends a lot on the actual features you're implementing. But, at the end of the day, the API will have to be merged on master first, and all UI changes tested against this master branch. But, again, better be flexible and have a workflow adapted to the features asked rather than have a static workflow.

Comment: Thanks @ÉricCôté.  We ended up adding a git push hook in the UI repo that asks the dev for the API branch to test against.  We then fire off a Travis job to run the tests.  It's a short term solution but is the best bang for our buck right now.